# Initial indexation in Hibernate Search with Elasticsearch crashes

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, playframework, playframework-2.0, hibernate-search

I'm trying to add Hibernate Search's Elasticsearch implementation to an existing project.

Everything seems to be okay, my updated and new entities are indexed to Elastic, but when I try to index existing data into Elasticsearch (using the snipped provided in documentation), I've got an error and the whole application crashes.

**The indexation code**

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(JPA.em());
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

**Error trace**

```
[error] o.h.s.e.i.LogErrorHandler - HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH400007: Elasticsearch request failed.
 Request:
========
Operation: DeleteByQuery
URI:models.project.project/models.project.Project/_query
Data:
{ "query" : { "constant_score" : { "filter" : { "match_all" : { } } } } }
Response:
=========
Status: 404
Error message: 404 Not Found
Cluster name: null
Cluster status: null


Primary Failure:
        Entity models.project.Project  Id null  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.PurgeAllLuceneWork
Subsequent failures:
        Entity models.project.Project  Id null  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.PurgeAllLuceneWork

org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH400007: Elasticsearch request failed.
 Request:
========
Operation: DeleteByQuery
URI:models.project.project/models.project.Project/_query
Data:
{ "query" : { "constant_score" : { "filter" : { "match_all" : { } } } } }
Response:
=========
Status: 404
Error message: 404 Not Found
Cluster name: null
Cluster status: null


        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.JestClient.executeRequest(JestClient.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.JestClient.executeRequest(JestClient.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.SingleRequest.doExecute(SingleRequest.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.SingleRequest.execute(SingleRequest.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.BackendRequestProcessor.doExecute(BackendRequestProcessor.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.BackendRequestProcessor.executeSync(BackendRequestProcessor.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchIndexManager.performOperations(ElasticsearchIndexManager.java:406)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.LocalBackendQueueProcessor.applyWork(LocalBackendQueueProcessor.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.WorkQueuePerIndexSplitter.commitOperations(WorkQueuePerIndexSplitter.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.batch.DefaultBatchBackend.sendWorkToShards(DefaultBatchBackend.java:79)
Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.getIdentifierName()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchIndexingWorkspace.<init>(BatchIndexingWorkspace.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchCoordinator.doBatchWork(BatchCoordinator.java:131)
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchCoordinator.runWithErrorHandler(BatchCoordinator.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.ErrorHandledRunnable.run(ErrorHandledRunnable.java:32)me()Ljava/lang/String;

        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.MassIndexerImpl.startAndWait(MassIndexerImpl.java:213)
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchIndexingWorkspace.<init>(BatchIndexingWorkspace.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchCoordinator.doBatchWork(BatchCoordinator.java:131)
        at models.project.Project.reindex(Project.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchCoordinator.runWithErrorHandler(BatchCoordinator.java:97)
        at controllers.ProjectController.reindex(ProjectController.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.ErrorHandledRunnable.run(ErrorHandledRunnable.java:32)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$12$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Routes.scala:967)
        at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.MassIndexerImpl.startAndWait(MassIndexerImpl.java:213)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$12$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Routes.scala:967)
        at models.project.Project.reindex(Project.java:253)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
        at controllers.ProjectController.reindex(ProjectController.java:80)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$12$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Routes.scala:967)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:156)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$12$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Routes.scala:967)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:13 at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
6)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:73)
        at play.http.HttpRequestHandler$1.call(HttpRequestHandler.java:54)
        at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.lambda$call$4(TransactionalAction.java:28)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.lambda$withTransaction$3(DefaultJPAApi.java:196)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:137)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:195)
        at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:25)
        at security.CheckAction.lambda$call$0(CheckAction.java:47)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:137)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:95)
        at security.CheckAction.call(CheckAction.java:41)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:56)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:48)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:111)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:110)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:110)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:103)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:409)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="history.HistoryInterceptor" />

        <property name="hibernate.search.elasticsearch.host" value="http://localhost:9200" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager" value="elasticsearch" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.index_management_strategy" value="CREATE" />


    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Any idea how to index initial data without this error?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the delete by query plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html

See this paragraph in our documentation for information on how to configure your Elasticsearch cluster: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_elasticsearch_configuration .

Note that the plugin has been integrated in Elasticsearch 5 but we don't support Elasticsearch 5 yet.

Comment: I had no idea that the indexation needed this plugin. Maybe it should be more explicit in the documentation.
Anyway, thanks Guillaume !

Comment: Ticket created to address this issue with the docs: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2569